# SQL count quantity of SOLD CARS and count DIFFERENT COLOR

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

i want to show how many cars where sold and which color they had.

I need to show all car brands that are in table: cars. The total quantity of cars that where sold (see table: car_sales) and how many of these cars have the color red or blue.

It should look like this:

```
Car        | totalQuantity | Quantity red | Quantity blue
------------------------------------------------------------
BMW        |      3        |      1       |        2
Mercedes   |      1        |      1       |        0
Audi       |      2        |      2       |        0 
Chevrolet  |      0        |      0       |        0
Nissan     |      1        |      0       |        1 
Renault    |      0        |      0       |        0
Peugeot    |      0        |      0       |        0
```

these are my two tables:

table: cars

```
  Car_id   | Car_brand         
------------------------
  2356     | BMW        
  2359     | Mercedes   
  2358     | Audi 
  2544     | Chevrolet         
  2152     | Nissan  
  2245     | Renault
  2253     | Peugeot
```

table: car_sales

```
  sales_id     | Car_brand | color     | car_id  | sales_date
---------------------------------------------------------------
  45654556     | BMW       |  red      |  2356   | 03.02.2009 
  63654552     | Mercedes  |  red      |   ...   |    ... 
  45654565     | BMW       |  blue     |   ...   |    ...
  41456921     | Audi      |  red      |         |
  36636545     | Nissan    |  blue     |         |
  45654565     | BMW       |  blue     |         |
  41456921     | Audi      |  red      |         |
```

I Hope you can help me.
Have a nice day.

Comment: You've done a very nice job explaining what you want to do; the only thing missing is the SQL you've written to try and do this yourself. Please [edit] and show at least some effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Because `PIVOT` is an 11g and greater feature, could you specify your Oracle version?

Comment: Just a remark: Your table design is redundant. Usually you would want to get rid of the car_brand column in car_sales, because the information is available in table cars. (In a data warehouse system you might want to get rid of the table cars instead, so there is still redundancy but easy access without the need to join tables.)

Answer (score 1):

If the colors are fixed to red and blue the following should work:

```
select c.brand, 
       count(*) as total_quantity,
       count(case when cs.color = 'red' then 1 end) as quantity_red,
       count(case when cs.color = 'blue' then 1 end) as quantity_blud
from cars c
  join car_sales cs on c.car_id = cs.car_id
group by c.brand;
```

If you have more colors (but still a fix number) you might want to look into the `PIVOT` operator (search this site, there is a tag for this).

If you have an unknown number of colors this is going to be messy, as you need dynamic SQL and stored procedures - in that case something like that is better done in a reporting tool (e.g. Excel is pretty good in doing pivot queries)